# ASIHTTPRequest compile/link issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, asihttprequest

When I was trying to add ASIHTTPRequest for an iPhone project, I ran into many compiling/Linking problems even after following the instructions [allseeing-i](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions).

So after comparing my new project with the working project from the allseing-i I found out that the tutorial have missed a few things:

1. Not all the frameworks that the project needs are mentioned to be included. My project was missing **libxml2.2.7.3.dylib** actually.
2. Then there is another configuration in the "Target Settings" search for "**Header Search Paths**" and add the path: **${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2** , make sure you actually select the checkbox. this will direct the compiler to the libxml2 files which you will be getting errors from.

This should be enough to actually get the project up and running! :)

Comment: I was able to get the ASIHTTPRequest working with the instructions behind your link. Make sure you only add the files listed in the instructions to your project, as libxml2 is not needed by the core files. The following link describes how to add libxml2 to get ASIWebPageRequest working: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest .

Comment: yes, the instructions on their website work fine, as i've used it numerous times successfully and happily.  Looks like you installed something optional (the XML portion from your library). no downvote, but i did vote to close as its misleading/not a question.

Comment: Hi Jesse, Sorry for the misleading "Question" I did want to post this somewhere and since i use stackOverflow most of the time, i chose to put it here.